# Accessing my object properties in an array

Tags: javascript, titanium

```
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:50});
    var rowData = [];
    row.add(PrimeSuiteUserName);
    row.add(PrimeSuiteUserPassword);
    Ti.API.info("HelloRow" +row);
    rowData[0] = Object.property1;
    rowData[1] = Object.property1;
    Ti.API.info("Hello" +rowData);
```

When i alert down my row object i get this...

```
HelloRow[Ti.UI.TableViewRow]
```

How can i access my row object property in my array.

Comment: When you say 'my array' do you mean the `rowData` array? I'm also unsure as to why you're reading `Object.property1` and what precisely you mean by 'my row object property'.

Comment: i want to hold the object values in my rowData array

Comment: I still don't follow, sorry. Maybe someone else will understand and help.

Comment: object holds some value and how can i access them

Comment: Do you want to get your table row properties like row title? And may be you are getting these properties on table/row click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
// section index
var sectionIndex = 0;

// row index
var rowIndex = 0

// without label or childfield
rowtitle = yourTableView.data[sectionIndex].rows[rowIndex].title;
Ti.API.info("HelloRow " +rowtitle);

// child index
var childIndex = 0;

// with label or childfield
var text = yourTableView.data[sectionIndex].rows[rowIndex].children[childIndex].text;
Ti.API.info("HelloRow " +text);
```

Comment: How to access a row's selectedIndex

Comment: yourTableView.addEventListener('click',function(e){ selectedRowIndex = e.index;})